# Comportamiento Raro de vue - componentes + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

he clonado mi propio proyecto de Github porque cometí un error y decidí hacerlo mejor así.

Entonces, todo había estado funcionando correcto, pero al momento de correr mis componentes de vue tuve errores, ya no recuerdo que comando introduje para que funcionara.

esto es lo que me salía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que tanto movi, pero medió funciona. al menos .

así tengo mi Package Json

```html
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.6.7",
        "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.3",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.1.1",
        "apexcharts": "^2.1.9",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "ckeditor": "^4.10.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.3",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.2.2",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
        "vue-content-placeholders": "^0.2.1",
        "vue-toasted": "^1.1.25",
        "vue-truncate-filter": "^1.1.7",
        "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.2",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
    }
}
```

pero ahora me sale este mensaje.

```html
    14% building modules 39/79 modules 40 active ...ces/js/components/foro/comments.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
 95% emitting
```

pero también me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero tanto como me sale ese error, me sale que todo ha sido correcto. Y me muestra los cambios. pero es molesto trabajar así. lo cual antes no me salía nada de eso. NO entiendo porque.

Comment: Borraste el node_modules y volviste a hacer un nmp i?

Comment: @gbianchi si de hecho eso hice y entonces funciono.  pero funciona con esos mensajes que son molestos

Comment: actualizaste algun paquete de mas, y por eso sera el problema?

Comment: @gbianchi de hecho cuando vi que no funcionaba, se había instalado nuevos paquetes en package json se veían reflejados. entonces me fui a mi proyecto de github donde ese funciona bien y copie lo mismo  que estaba en el json solo puse npm install & composer. porque borre todo.